# An exception occurred when setting up mail server parameters.: cfpop

Tags: coldfusion

the below code was working until a few days back, but it started giving exception

```
<cfpop
    action="getall"
    name="qMessage"
    server="mail.forestweb.com"
    port="995"
    username="email***@industryintel.com"
    password="******"
    timeout="30"
/>
```

I am running this code every 10 minutes to fetch the emails. And getting following exceptions:

```
Message: An exception occurred when setting up mail server parameters.
Detail : This exception was caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: 
Connect failed; nested exception is: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out.
```

Can anyone please tell me why this is happening and if it has any solutions.

Comment: Add the debug="true" attribute. What do you see in the logs ie {cf_root}/runtime/logs/coldfusion-out.log ?

Comment: Verbose Logging +1 

If the mailserver is up and running and you can be sure, that port 995 is open on both sides (no newly introduced firewall restrictions and the like) then check if the IP of the mailserver has changed recently. In this case it could be a DNS caching problem of the underlying JVM. Make sure you tried restarting/rebooting the ColdFusion Server.

Comment: thanks Andreas will try that. This code was not working on our staging server but on live server its working fine. Will try restarting staging Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

The root cause for me, when I had this problem, was that my harddrive was nearly full combined with the fact that there were some invalid spool files in the spool directory.

I cleared some space on the harddrive that my cf server was on and the email started sending again.

Answer (score 1):

Port 995 is typically used for SSL secured connections. Natively, CFPOP does not support SSL. However, there is a way, check out this post http://www.thecfguy.com/post.cfm/ssl-support-with-cfpop

Hope that helps.